# Kubernetes share data between containers

Tags: kubernetes, volumes

I am exercising on K8S, and I need to share some data between my containers inside a POD, the problem I have is that I need to make containers have available some data from other containers that is already present on that containers at startup. Let me show an example of what I mean:

Container A at startup:
`/root/dir/a.txt`
Container B at startup `/root/dirB/b.txt`

In container C I want to have a directory that contains both a.txt file and b.txt file without doing any operation such as writing etc. But just using volumes.
How can I do it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a emptyDir volume, mount it at `/newroot` on both A and B with both of those set as initContainers which will run `command: [bash, -c, "cp /root/dir/a.txt /newroot/dir/a.txt]` and similar for B. On C mount that emptyDir using `subPath` on either `/root/dir` or the whole path as needed.